# get the address bar url instead of request url

Tags: php, url, laravel-5

I have the page test_page with the url `http://domain.sd/test_page` which is in the address bar.
I have used the controller with url filter_details in the same page in ajax response. I want to get the address in the address bar.
Now I can get only the ajax request url

```
 $url=\Request::getRequestUri();
   echo $url; // output: filter_details
```

How to get the address in the address bar

Comment: What do you want to achieve by that? Why not send that URL through the AJAX request?

Answer (score 3):

The PHP-Server only knows the context of a request.

If you use another URL for your ajax request, there is no way for PHP to know the current address displayed in the address bar of your browser.

Try to pass the url in the address bar by parameter / data with the ajax request. You can get your current address in the browser on the client side with `window.location` and pass it as a query or payload data with your request, depending on your ajax method (GET or POST).

Answer (score -2):

You can get browser's URL in laravel by using :

```
\Request::server('HTTP_REFERER');
```

Or in PHP You can use

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

The HTTP referer header is set by the user agent and contains the URI of the page. For example , if you click a link on the page abc.com/page to go to another-pqrl.com/link, the HTTP Referer received by another-pqrl.com/link will have the value abc.com/page.

In laravel version 5.5 , I am using $templateAppSlug = \Request::server('HTTP_REFERER'); And I am getting URL as output value.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Usually, the referer contains a different URL

Comment: This would be in direct contravention to [the RFC definition of `Referer`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-14.36). I'm not quite sure where you got the idea otherwise - would be curious to hear which browser sends "the browser's URL" in the `Referer` header.

Comment: The HTTP referer header is set by the user agent and contains the URI of the page. For example , if you click a link on the page abc.com/page to go to another-pqrl.com/link, the HTTP Referer received by another-pqrl.com/link will have the value abc.com/page.

Comment: I am using $templateAppSlug = \Request::server('HTTP_REFERER'); And I am getting URL as output value.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it. The referer is still something completely different

Comment: Still: keep in mind that the referer is the URL that was accessed before the current URL, and the **current** URL is to be gathered in the original question

Comment: Yes, but like the question asked, user/questioner wanted the old url and not the current url(called by ajax) so this would give the required ouput. And I can say this because I had the same requirement and with this answer I got the required url as output

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it